# How to prepare long posts with mathjax?

Tags: discussion, mathjax, editor, formatting

How do you guys prepare long posts for SE; particularly for those that support mathjax?

Answer (score 3):

I write them in a plain text file (in my case with gedit or Geany) and translate with [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/):

```
pandoc --mathjax -s -o post.html post.md
```

That gives you a pretty good idea of what to expect on SE, provided you don't use Markdown features one of pandoc and SE does not support.

I should maybe note that I keep a record of the images I create (in files) since they tend to be *very* time-consuming and sources don't end up on SE. I can only recommend using TikZ for this purpose, though, as the results are very nice. See [here](http://akerbos.github.io/sesketches/) for details.

Comment: Ah, nice gallery. Is that a custom HTML page, or is there a nice way to host such a gallery? Indeed it would be nice if one can include sources to images (I tried keeping graphviz image sources in comments, it didn't turn out so well IIRC; in the meantime I keep the sources in my stackedit draft), perhaps in a spoiler-like tag that would default to collapsed.

Comment: @RealzSlaw That's a custom-built PHP script. If there is interest I am happy to share, though. I link the sources as you can see in the resp. posts; they have no good place on SE (spoiler tags don't collapse!). You could use pastebin or something like that, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

I used to use notepages ([demo](http://notepag.es), [project](https://github.com/fivesixty/notepages)). It was slightly annoying, because they use different open/close symbols for mathjax.

Then I started using [stackedit](http://benweet.github.io/stackedit/) ([project](https://github.com/benweet/stackedit)), which works great, and integrates well with Google Docs/Drive and Dropbox. You can even install it as an App under google docs, which will create a stackedit document that will automatically save there.

Comment: Wow, StackEdit seems to be very useful. Good find!